# Transfering comments from a Facebook page to a website

Tags: facebook, web, comments

I'm aware that Facebook Developers offer a plugin for websites that allows users to comments on an article via their Facebook account.

However, my question is whether comments from a Facebook page can be transferred automatically to a website. For example: for a Facebook page belonging to a newspaper, when an article is published on the the wall of the newspaper's Facebook page, and when people comment or "like" that article, can these comments and likes be transferred automatically to the article on the newspaper's website that is fully integrated with the plugin. Or are comments on an article posted on the Facebook page wall completely different and incompatible with comments on an article posted on the website's page?

Thanks for your help!

Best,
V

Answer (score 1):

You will have to programmatically use the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) to retrieve the comments left on your Facebook page posts, then render these on your corresponding articles on your Web site.

The [Facebook Comment plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) loads comments tied to specific URLs (e.g., yoursite.com/article/123).  Facebook will not relate these to specific posts on your Wall for you.